# How to configure SSL certificate on Tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I purchased SSL certificate from GeoTrust for my client’s web app.( I am using Tomcat 6). From GeoTrust I got following files.

1. CACertificate-INTERMEDIATE-1.cer
2. CACertificate-ROOT-2.cer
3. ServerCertificate.cer
4. PKCS7.p7b
5. private key.txt
6. mycert.jks

I had not created private key or CSR. That process was completed by the company from which I had purchased SSL certificate.  Now when I followed the steps mentioned at link (http://www.geotrust.eu/en/support/manuals/tomcat/tomcat+webserver/install+certificate/) I am not able to configure the SSL. I have following doubts

1. Steps in above link mentioned “.crt” *but* I am having “.cer” files. Is it same?
2. Following is initial lines of my .jks file *before* following Steps from above link. Is it sufficient?

```
 Keystore type: JKS
 Keystore provider: SUN

 Your keystore contains 1 entry

 Alias name: www.myclientname.com
 Creation date: 2 Feb, 2017
 Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
 Certificate chain length: 3
```

3. After following steps from above link, Last message of Keytool should be "Certificate reply was installed in keystore". BUT I am getting message as "Certificate Added in keystore successfully". I think it’s not added into my certificate?

I had tested using Self-signed (un-trusted) certificate and it works properly but when I tried to configure following lines in server.xml it won’t works.

```
<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="my_keystore_with_full_path" keypass="my_keystore_password" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> I HAD NOT CREATED PRIVATE KEY OR CSR. That process was completed by the company from which I had purchased SSL certificate.

Your own evidence disproves it. A third party cannot do this for you, by definition. Otherwise your private key wouldn't be private.

> 2. Following is initial lines of my .jks file BEFORE following Steps from above link. Is it sufficient?

Not only is it sufficient, it completely disproves your assertion that you didn't generate a private key. You did, and here it is. You would also have generated the CSR.

All you have to do now is import the signed certificate, using the same alias.

> 3. After following steps from above link, Last message of Keytool should be "Certificate reply was installed in keystore". BUT I am getting message as "Certificate Added in keystore successfully". I think it’s not added into my certificate?

Correct. The final instruction in the link is incorrect. When importing the actual signed certificate, you should *not* use the `-trustcacerts` option. You should only use that for the a Root and Intermediate certificates. You should complain about that error to the vendor.